# How to set multiple Mappers in Reduce Join algorithms?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In the Reduce side join algorithm two mapper classes are used. But none of them are set in the driver class of my code.Only the reducer is set.
How does the job know which mapper class to use?
And how can we set multiple mapper classes to a job?
I am using hadoop 2.2

Thanks and regards,
Dheeraj
PS: I just copy pasted the problem from an email which I had sent to my instructor so some of you might have seen his name appearing in the question.
Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer .. for multiple mapper it is set in 
MultipleInputs.addInputPath();